# How to properly use $watch in a directive inside a "controller as" controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-watch

Here is my JS code. The objective is to create a directive that changes the associated DOM element visibility on a scope variable change, but here I've just replaced the code by an 'alert' intruction to get a minimal (not) working example.

```
app.directive( 'myDirective', [ function () {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
           scope.$watch( 'configurationMode', function( newValue ) {
               alert("TOTO");
           }, true );
       }
   };
} ]);

app.controller( 'ControlPanelController', function() {
    this.configurationMode = true;

    // and some additional code that 
    // modifies 'configurationMode'
    // in response to UI events
});
```

And I use the directive in the HTML in a straightforward way:

```
<div my-directive>
    ...
</div>
```

`alert('TOTO')` is called once at the first digest cycle, but not once after that, even though the `configurationMode` variable changes value (which I can see on the UI). What is wrong with the code?

This is the first time I use the 'controller as' syntax with my controller. Is this the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach `configurationMode` to the `scope` in your controller. `scope.$watch` only watches properties on the scope.

There's a couple hacks for watching variables attached to your controller. One might be using controller as, say controller as $ctrl, then `scope.$watch('$ctrl.configurationMode', function(){})`.

I would just using bindings, a two way binding, and pass the value through the bind on your directive... the syntax is different depending on what version of AngularJS/Angular you are using.

```
.directive( 'myDirective', [ function () {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope:{
            configurationMode: '='
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.$watch('configurationMode', function(newValue) {
               alert("TOTO");
           }, true);
       }
   };
}]);
```

then to use it

```
<div my-directive configuration-mode="$ctrl.configurationMode"></div>
```

My AngularJS 1.x is a little rusty so check the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
I'm guessing you're using an AngularJS 1.x because you have a restrict: 'A' property on your directive.

Comment: Ok. "Attach the variable to the scope in the controller", as you suggest, means adding something like `$scope.configMode = this.configMode` in the controller (as well as making the variable as an object so that the reference and not the value is shared between controller and $scope objects), is that right?

Comment: Another question. Regarding the first hack you suggest, "using controller as, say controller as $ctrl", where should I add this piece of code? I know its use in ng-controller but not inside a directive...

Comment: Yes to the first question (and try it see what happens). Yes you do it in ng-controller. But when angularjs does the evaluation it's in a context that knows what $ctrl is.